# How can I securely transmit data between applications

Tags: android, security

I want to transmit a small amount of data between a Service and an Activity. These are separate applications. Ideally, I'd just pack my data (and a nonce for confirmation) into an Intent and use that. But per Mark Murphy's blog post [Warning: Activity Intent Extras Can Be Public](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/30/warning-activity-intent-extras-public.html) I know this is not safe.

Is [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) safe?

Is there a better way to do what I want?

---

Here is my use case:

Service A is going to launch Activity B with an Intent and ask the question "Is operation X authorized?". User action may be required, so that's why I'm launching an Activity from a Service.

I want Activity B to answer simply "yes" or "no". I want to make sure a malicious app on the device can't spoof that response. My current code uses an Intent to send the response.

I'm taking a defense-in-depth approach, and part of that is that I don't want the request from A to B to be readable by anybody else. Among other things, I intend to pack a nonce into the original request

---

Answering @mwhs' questions:

Service is only asking a yes/no question. I want to be very sure that the response comes from who I'm expecting it from. A nonce should do the trick, but it would need to be transmitted securely.

I'm not a security expert other than a little dabbling. What do you mean by "receipt of that very nonce on the initial sender side must carry a proof, that the intended party actually replied with that nonce, ideally by binding the nonce (or a decrement of it) cryptographically to a proof of identity (which can be usage of a shared good key for instance)"?

Assuming I can get the nonce securely to the other party, doesn't the fact that the other party responds with it constitute proof that they're the intended party? How do I "bind" the nonce to proof of identity? Some sort of HMAC? And why decrement it; is that some sort of hash-buster?

I'm a little leery of embedding shared secrets into an app that could theoretically be reverse-engineered.

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`? That blog post is from 2011, and the bug there has since been fixed. It is also only relevant for a `startActivity()` call, and it would be somewhat unusual for a service to be calling `startActivity()`. I would recommend that you edit your question and explain, in much greater detail, the flows and nature of your desired inter-process communication.

Comment: you could have a shared key and encrypt the data you send

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks for the update. Does this mean that Intent data is now private between sender and receiver?  I'll edit my question to add more detail:

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan yes, I'm considering that approach, but would like to avoid it if I can secure communications otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Service A is going to launch Activity B with an Intent and ask the question "Is operation X authorized?". User action may be required, so that's why I'm launching an Activity from a Service.

For ordinary apps on ordinary devices, this is not a recommended approach, unless you are damn sure that the user won't regret you taking over the foreground with your activity.

> I want Activity B to answer simply "yes" or "no". I want to make sure a malicious app on the device can't spoof that response.

The blog post that you cite refers to a bug that used to exist in Android, for extras packaged on an `Intent` used for `startActivity()`. Your scenario, as described, does not involve this, as you did not mention any extras on the `Intent` passed from Service A to Activity B. Plus, that bug has since been fixed, though I forget exactly where in the 4.x series it was fixed.

> My current code uses an Intent to send the response.

That's not a particularly informative statement. That's akin to saying that you use a string to send the response. A string or an `Intent` may be the *format* of the response, but somehow you need to use inter-process communication (IPC) to get that response back to Service A.

One non-option is `startActivityForResult()`, as that is only available to activities, not services.

Possible IPC options include:

1. Calling `startService()` on the service, passing the `Intent`, using a custom `signature` permission to ensure that only your apps can call `startService()` on that service.
2. Calling `bindService()` on the service, waiting to get the binder, then passing the `Intent` (or whatever) to some method that you implement on the `Binder` (and using the same custom `signature` permission as above).
3. Passing a `PendingIntent` from Service A to Activity B as an extra, and having Activity B fill and execute that `PendingIntent`. You would use a `signature` permission or validating the signing key of Activity B's app to ensure that Service A only sends this to the correct app. And, you'd need to research the exact point when the problem that I outlined in the blog post got fixed.
4. Passing a `ResultReceiver` from Service A to Activity B (which otherwise works much as would the `PendingIntent` scenario above)
5. Having Service A register a `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()`, then have Activity B send a broadcast matching the receiver's `IntentFilter`. You would need to go the custom `signature` permission route.
6. Doing something outside the Android component system (e.g., using an HTTP daemon in the service that the activity talks to). Ick.

Note that [custom permissions suck](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md), at least before Android 5.0.

Other than the now-fixed recent-activities `Intent` leak, I am not aware of any current means for spying on IPC, except:

- rooted devices
- custom ROMs
- impersonation (e.g., Service A talks to Activity M from a malware author that is masquerading as Activity B)

The latter scenario is where `signature` permissions or validating the signing key of Activity B's app come into play.

Anything that is exported (scenarios #1, #2, #5) is at risk of spoofing. `signature` permissions help, except that custom permissions suck. I would lean towards #3 or #4.

Depending on what other communications are going on between these apps, there may be other options (e.g., long-term bound service, with callback objects to provide bi-directional communication).

Comment: OK, answering more questions: Given the nature of the application, an Activity popping up to ask the user a question will not be intrusive. The initial Service request to the Activity will contain a nonce; that's the part I want to protect. The Activity sends its response back to the Service via a boolean extra in an Intent which is received in `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Per your suggestions: 1. I'll definitely be using the signature permission; that's part of my defense in depth. 2. My understanding is that ResultReceiver is a wrapper around Binder, which is why I was considering it. 3. I was also considering PendingIntent.

Comment: Anyway, knowing that the Intent leak bug is now fixed, I'll just see if I can find exactly which SDK fixes it, and set that to my MinSDK. That will simplify things greatly; thank you. I too am leaning toward solution #4 plus signature permissions to prevent impersonation. I've considered a Bound application, but these security requests are not frequent and the yes/no Activity will not be hanging around. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: "I'll definitely be using the signature permission; that's part of my defense in depth" -- set your `minSdkVersion` to 21. "set that to my MinSDK" -- while you're welcome to use my `PermissionUtils` to try to detect attackers who exploit the custom permissions flaws pre-Android 5.0, I would recommend just limiting your app to Android 5.0 and higher.

Comment: Thanks. I just finished reading your essay on why permissions are broken. Very useful.